# ¿Cómo restaurar un permalink en Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Tengo un sitio web en wordpress, el problema es que hice una prueba con mi página **login** y renombré el permalink de **sitio.com/login** a **sitio.com/login-test**. Terminando las pruebas, quise regresar ese permalink a **login**, pero wordpress me lo cambia a **login-2** automáticamente.

¿Cómo puedo restaurar el permalink al estado anterior?

Comment: Por lo general Wordpress te pone un `2` porque **ya existe otro post o página con el mismo slug (enlace permanente)** (o sea, la parte de la URL que pones en el cuadro blanco, que sigue a tu dominio, cuando creas el post o página). Creo es es ese el problema en este caso. Ya tienes una con el slug `login` y cuando creas otra con el mismo slug, Wordpress le pone automáticamente un `2`, porque no pueden existir slug repetidos.

Comment: Hola! Lamento la tardanza para responder. El post que tenía el slug login, es el mismo que renombré a login-test, y posteriormente quise volver a llarmalo login. No tengo otra página con el slug login ahora mismo

Answer (score 1):

Para que use el nombre de la página como enlace permanente debes hacer lo siguiente:

<kbd>**1**</kbd> Ir a **`Ajustes`** en el panel de Wordpress

<kbd>**2**</kbd> Ir a **`Enlaces permanentes`**

<kbd>**3**</kbd> Marcar la opción  **`Nombre de la entrada`**

<kbd>**4**</kbd> Verificar que en el cuadro de la opción **`Estructura personalizada`** **hay escrito solamente esto: `/%postname%/`**. Nótese que esta opción **no hay que marcarla**.

<kbd>**5**</kbd> Guardar los cambios pulsando el botón  **`Guardar cambios`**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si haciendo esto te sigue poniendo un `2`, significa que tienes dos elementos: posts, páginas o cualesquiera otros, que se llaman igual.